# $b^\frac{\log_b n}{n} = n^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This may seem incredibly basic, but I'm reviewing all laws of exponents, and I can't reason why this reduces as such.

I won't be able to sleep until I can rationalize this, so if someone would please refresh me on the reduction that makes this work.

given $b$ and $ n$ are positive, real numbers
$$b^\frac{\log_b n}{n} = n^\frac{1}{n}$$

thank you for your help.

Comment: $$ \Large b^{(\log_b n)/n}=\sqrt[n]{b^{\log_b n}}=\sqrt[n]{n} $$

Comment: Hints: in positive numbers $\displaystyle\;b^{\,p\,q} = \left(b^p\right)^q\,$ and $\,\displaystyle\;b^{\log_b n} = n\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one rule:

$\frac 1n(\log_b n) = \log_b (n^{\frac 1n})$

another rule

$b^{\log_b x} = x$

put 'em together and what do you have?

Comment: thank you!  I am rather embarrassed that I couldn't rationalize that.  but, slowly putting my math pants back on, one leg at a time...

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\left(b^{\frac{\log_bn}{n}}\right)^n=\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n$$ or
$$b^{\log_bn}=n,$$
which is true by the definition of $\log$.